# How do I organize SCSS in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I just bootstrapped a new rails project and I was trying to reference from an open sourced rails project on how they architect their app.

> [Link to the open sourced project](https://github.com/assemblymade/meta)

I noticed they have multiple layouts e.g. admin, application, home ..etc. And each may load in different stylesheets via `stylesheet_link_tag`.

For example in `focus_home.html.erb`:

```
<!-- Load styles -->
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'focus_home' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'app/components/modal' %>
```

And in their `app/assets/stylesheets` directory, they have `focus_home.scss`

I try to follow their architecture where I have multiple css files and I call different stylesheets with different layout.

I created my `home.scss` to be used by `home.html.slim`

when I started my rails server and try to load the `home` page, the following error occurs

```
Asset filtered out and will not be served: add
`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( home.css )` to
`config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server
```

Basically it asked me to tell rails to precompile `home.scss`. However, when I browse through the open source project's code base. It doesn't seem to have this line of code. The precompilation just seem to happen like magic.

So I am wondering what I am missing ?

==============

Edit: Further explain the case

In their project they *DO NOT* have an `application.css` file like normal rails project.

```
/*  * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files  * listed below.  * 
* Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,  * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.  *  * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the  * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles  * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new  * file per style scope.  *  *= require_tree .  *= require_self  */
```

Instead, in their `application.scss`, it goes like

```
@charset "utf-8";

@import "vars/base";
@import "constants";

// Libraries
@import 'bootstrap';

@import 'app/mixins/*';

@import 'basscss';

@import '_deprecated/basspluss';
@import '_deprecated/utility';
@import '_deprecated/nocss_vars';
@import '_deprecated/nocss';
@import '_deprecated/nocss_mq';

@import "app/main";

@import "base/*";
@import "utilities/*";
@import "app/components/*";
@import "components/*";
@import "app/slop";

@import 'libs/owl.carousel';
@import 'libs/owl.transitions';
@import 'libs/owl.theme';

@import 'c3/c3'
```

So I wonder how they actually do their precompilation??

Comment: import your file in `application.scss`, it should be in the `app/assets` folder

Comment: In the open sourced projects, it's under `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`

Comment: ah ok it's not your project, well im not sure what's the structure, but you can add your file in a folder that's included inside the `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` file

Comment: The thing i am not too sure about is how they handle CSS precompilation. It seems seems they don't have an `application.css` that `requires self and tree`

Comment: they don't need it, `application.scss` acts as the main

Comment: I have `application.scss` and `home.scss` in my directory. When I do `= stylesheet_link_tag 'application'` it works fine. However, when I do `=stylesheet_link_tag 'home'` it throws the message `Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetFilteredError in Pages#home` and `Asset filtered out and will not be served: add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( home.css )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server`

Comment: But I don't see the open sourced projects need to add `%w(home.css)` to `initializers/assets.rb`. In fact, they don't have an `assets.rb`

Comment: In fact, when I actually create `assets.rb` and do `Rails.Application.config.assets.precompile += %w(home.css)` it works. But I don't see the open sourced project does it at all so I am very interested to know where the magic happens

Comment: yea i can see your point now, I can't figure it out my self

Comment: It's okay! thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use Sprockets comments in your application.scss and [must only use `@import` CSS rules](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#important-note).

From rails-sass documentation:

> Sprockets provides some directives that are placed inside of comments
>   called require, require_tree, and require_self. DO NOT USE THEM IN
>   YOUR SASS/SCSS FILES. They are very primitive and do not work well
>   with Sass files. Instead, use Sass's native @import directive which
>   sass-rails has customized to integrate with the conventions of your
>   Rails projects.

Then, if you have any other .scss that needs to be precompiled, you will have to explicitly add them using the `Rails.Application.config.assets.precompile` directive, then the sprockets railtie will do the rest of the job!

To answer your original question, the reason why the open source project do not need to specify assets to precompile is because they are using `config.assets.compile = true` in the config/environment/production.rb file. This is obviously a very bad practice and I don't recommend you to switch this directive to `true` in a production environment... you will end up with a slow code making a lot of requests and there a slow page load.

Comment: Ya I think you missed the question. The question is really about how the open sourced project managed to precompile multiple scss without calling `config.assets.precompile` ~

Comment: Therefore you recommend actually using `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( a.css b.css c.css ... )` and indicating precompilation of css one by one?

Comment: You're right! at least in a production environment. If you compile "on the fly" on production that will seriously slow down your page load.